# Converting month_year variable into week_year (dplyr) & (lubridate)

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr, graph, lubridate

I have a dataset structured as follows, where I am tracking collective action mentions by  subReddit by month, relative to a policy treatment which is introduced in Feb 17th, 2012. As a result, the period "Feb 2012" appears twice in my dataset where the "pre" period refers to the Feb 2012 days before treatment, and "post" otherwise.

```
treatment_status  month_year       collective_action_percentage
pre               Dec 2011           5%
pre               Jan 2012           8%
pre               Feb 2012           10%
post              Feb 2012           3%
post              March 2012        10%
```

However, I am not sure how to best visualize this indicator by month, but I made the following graph but I was wondering if presenting this pattern/variable by week&year, rather than month&year basis would be clearer if I am interested in showing how collective action mentions decline after treatment?

```
ggplot(data = df1, aes(x = as.Date(month_year), fill = collective_action_percentage ,y = collective_action_percentage)) +
    geom_bar(stat = "identity", position=position_dodge()) + 
    scale_x_date(date_breaks = "1 month", date_labels = "%b %Y") +
          scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent_format(accuracy = 1)) +
      xlab("Criticism by individuals active before and after treatment") + 
  theme_classic()+
    theme(plot.title = element_text(size = 10, face = "bold"),
          axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5))
```

output:
[image]

I created the month_year variable as follows using the Zoo package

```
df<- df %>%  
  mutate(month_year = zoo::as.yearmon(date))
```

Finally, I tried aggregating the data by weekly-basis as follows, however, given that I have multiple years in my dataset, I want to ideally aggregate data by week&year, and not simply by week

```
df2 %>% group_by(week = isoweek(time)) %>% summarise(value = mean(values))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plot a point for each row and connect them with a line so that it is clear what the order is.  We also color the pre and post points differently and make treatment status a factor so that we can order the pre level before the post level.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(zoo)

df2 <- transform(df1, month_year = as.yearmon(month_year, "%b %Y"),
  treatment_status = factor(treatment_status, c("pre", "post")))
ggplot(df2, aes(month_year, collective_action_percentage)) + 
  geom_point(aes(col = treatment_status), cex = 4) + 
  geom_line()
```

[image: screenshot]

### Note

We assume df1 is as follows. We have already removed % .

```
df1 <- 
structure(list(treatment_status = c("pre", "pre", "pre", "post", 
"post"), month_year = c("Dec 2011", "Jan 2012", "Feb 2012", "Feb 2012", 
"March 2012"), collective_action_percentage = c(5L, 8L, 10L, 
3L, 10L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```